# Default configuration for all HttpClient instances in .net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a scenario where I am configuring multiple `HttpClient` instances in `Startup.cs` which use same `HttpClientHandlers`. The only difference between those `HttpClients` is the `BaseAddress` property and the name of respective `HttpClient` instance since I'm using named `HttpClients`.

I was wondering if there is a possibility to create either a default `HttpClient` where I'd be adding all those handlers and then the named instances would inherit them or if there is some other way how can I centrally add those handlers without having to manually add them for each `HttpClient` instance.

```
private void ConfigureHttpClients(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient<IService1, Service>(client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.test.com/");
    })
    .UseErrorHandling()
    .UseDefaultHeaders();

    services.AddHttpClient<IService2, Service2>(client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.test-test.com/");
    })
    .UseErrorHandling()
    .UseDefaultHeaders();
}
```

Comment: Please post your `startup.cs`. Aren't you using [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#named-clients)?

Comment: @Fildor I added only the part I'd like to improve. The problem is I have much more handlers to add and also couple of services more. I know I could extract those settings somewhere in the configuration file and then loop through it, but I thought there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: @wegelagerer aren't you already doing what you want in this code? The functions you  use are just calls after all, you could put `UseErrorHandling().UseDefaultHeaders()` in a separate method and call that after `AddHttpClient`. Even that is just a call, which means you can create your own generic method that accepts the types as generic parameters and the base address, and use that instead of `AddHttpClient`

Comment: Ok, now I see. Much clearer.

Comment: The real problem is that, just like inheritance, you'll always find exceptions to the rule and have to use different configuration. In this case, the common config method becomes a problem - do you try to make it configurable, probably resulting in a mess and breaking other clients? Or copy the config calls for those specialized cases?

Comment: So yes, creating a default configuration is easy. You could even use an array with the types and URLs to configure all handlers at once, or use reflection to find all relevant services and add them. At some point though, some of those HttpClients will require special handling - perhaps they need different retry policies? Different headers? This doesn't mean the default config code is wrong, just be aware of the traps

Comment: Something like ... `public static void AddMyHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>( this IServiceCollection services, string baseUri ) {  services.AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(client => { client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri); }).UseErrorHandling().UseDefaultHeaders();}` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos To your first solution, that is something I could do it, I was hoping there is something like a default HttpClient which I could configure to contain configuration for all clients. But yes, you are definitely right, maybe I created a problem where there was none :) Thank you for all the infos!

Comment: @Fildor Nice solution - thank you! Add it as the answer to the solution because I will use something like this when there isn't default config for all used `HttpClients`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An improvement for the situation could be an extensionmethod like this:

```
public static void AddMyHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>( this IServiceCollection services, 
                                                              string baseUri ) 
{  
    services.AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(client => 
       { 
           client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri); 
       })
       .UseErrorHandling()
       .UseDefaultHeaders();
}
```

which can then be used as

```
services.AddMyHttpClient<IService1, Service>("http://api.test.com/");
```

in Startup.cs

---

UPDATE

If the Lambda gets mistaken for a `Func<HttpClient, TClient>` you'll get a "Not all code paths return a value".

You can fix this like so:

```
var configureAction = (HttpClient client) => { client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri); };
services.AddHttpClient<TClient, TImpl>(configureAction);
```

Seems strange, but I haven't found a better solution, yet.

Comment: Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression!

Comment: It is not supposed to. It is supposed to mutate the parameter.

Comment: No, I mean it won't compile as it breaks syntax, at least in dotnet 7

Comment: Then you might have to tweak it a little. I'll have a look later.

Comment: Somehow it seems to mistake this for a Func<HttpClient, TClient> ... I'll add a fix.

Comment: @steveoshima Updated answer.